# Deployment of asp.net 3.5 website: Requirements

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project

If i create website in asp.net 3.5 then does it require to have asp.net 2.0 framework in deployment enviorment?

Does website deployment project automatically include prerequisite for deployment or we should initially required to install all prerequisite at deployment enviounment before installing website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unlike going from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0, the .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 runtimes are layered on top of .NET 2.0 and require the runtimes to be installed.

As mentioned below though, the installer of .NET 3.5 will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en) on your webserver in order to run an ASP.NET 3.5 website.

A website deployment project *will not* do this for you - you will need to install this prior to your deployment to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.5 framework runs on top of the 2.0 runtime.  If you install the 3.5 framework you will get the 2.0 runtime on the server.

A website deployment project will not install any framework version on the server.  The purpose of the deployment projects are to compile your website pages so they don't have to JIT compile on the first requests to your website.